# Activating DLC maps on two consoles for Black Ops 2?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

My friend wanted to game-share my Black Ops 2 and Black Ops 1 maps along with some camos. I gave him my info to the account I bought them with, but he said I need to deactivate my account so he can go on my account and download the maps.

After he was finished activating/deactivating the accounts and downloading the maps, I checked Black Ops 2 and I didn't have my maps. What should I do?

Comment: What do 'bo1' and 'bo2' stand for?

Comment: Is it even possible to share DLCs? I don't think I've ever heard of this being possible.

Comment: You will need to activate your account again on the console. What you are doing is not supported -- account sharing is explicitly disallowed by Sony. @DJPirtu Black Ops 1, Black Ops 2.

Comment: Black ops 2 and Black ops 1

Comment: @TZHX alright thx

Comment: since i have 2 ps3s and 1 of them broke, i went on sony wbesite and deactivated my ps3

Comment: my friend is on my account right now downloading maps, after he is done should he acivate my acc  then go back on his other acc and activate it? Will i have my maps back?

Answer (score 1):

I got my maps back! I had to deactivate my old PS3 that is broken.

Thank you for your help.